RP2040 not going into BOOTSEL mode
My PC sees RP2040 as this device: 
Known facts:

I use OS Windows;
I have installed Pico SDK for VS Code and arm-gcc-none-eabi without any additional settings;
I have successfully generated test *.uf2 file so piko-sdk seems to be installed correctly;
My RP2040 installed to custom board. I know that It was flashed by the board manufacturer as UART-USB converter on one core and LED blink - on the other;
I am sure that USB cable that I`m using is data/sync cable (connected another device with that requires data transfers);
When I`m trying to access my RP using picotool I get:


"Device at bus 1, address 15 appears to be a RP2040 device with a USB
serial connection, not in BOOTSEL mode. You can force reboot into
BOOTSEL mode via 'picotool reboot    -f -u' first."

Using 'picotool reboot    -f -u' doesn`t make any effect. Command line executes command approx 1 seconds and there is no changes in device detection or working mode.
Using 'picotool reboot' gives this:

No accessible RP2040/RP2350 devices in BOOTSEL mode were found.
but:
Device at bus 1, address 15 appears to be a RP2040 device with a USB
serial connection, so consider -f to force the reboot

Is my RP2040 damaged? Or do I have to make some preparational steps to setup it as RPI-RP2 drive?

Have you tried the recommended method, i.e. hold down the BOOTSEL button before plugging in?

Yes, this method have also been tried. No effect
